# How to restructure multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with financial data, which looks like following:

```
                      Y0    Y1    Y2    Y3  
Variable1  Company1   0     2     4     5
           Company2   0     2     4     5
           Company3   0     2     4     5

Variable2  Company1   0     2     4     5
           Company2   0     2     4     5
           Company3   0     2     4     5
```

Is there a way to restructure the dataframe so it looks like this:

```
               Variable1     Variable2
Company1  Y0      0             0
          Y1      1             1
          Y2      2             2 
...
Company2  Y0      0             0
          Y1      1             1
          Y2      2             2
```

I have tried to reorder levels, but it doesn't give the result i want, since the lables are on different axis.

[data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YW15LXxYGFrwwpk_dzUQATUAkaRBqWxi)

Comment: What you want is `pivot_table`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
df.stack().unstack(0)
```

OUtput:

```
             Variable1  Variable2
Company1 Y0          0          0
         Y1          2          2
         Y2          4          4
         Y3          5          5
Company2 Y0          0          0
         Y1          2          2
         Y2          4          4
         Y3          5          5
Company3 Y0          0          0
         Y1          2          2
         Y2          4          4
         Y3          5          5
```